Issue using MJPEG Streaming on Raspberry Pi 5
I'm using the live streaming server recommended by the PiCamera2 documentation from https://github.com/raspberrypi/picamera2/blob/main/examples/mjpeg_server.py
But it only streams the top left corner of the camera feed.
I've changed the width/height of the PAGE and the size in the video configuration. Video_configuration improves the size of the video output but only up to a point, and the delay becomes massive as the size increases.
I've also tried using flask to stream the video with the same issue. I've unplugged and reconnected the camera very carefully too.
How can I get it to stream the full frame at lower quality/FPS?
The default preview window/first examples from the PiCamera2 documentation work with no issues.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
